# Multi-file log for an inner class using Log4j

Tags: java, logging

I have a class that is logging things in application log. I wanted to have something special logged to a separate file, so I created an inner class and modified the SpringConfig like this

```
log4j.logger.xxx.OuterClass.InnerClass=INFO, STALENESS

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(InnerClass.class);
```

And with appender `STALENESS` it should write to the new file.

I think this should work, but it didn't. It's still writing in the original file, except that it has an "appender" like: `04 Oct 2016 20:55:40,746 [INFO]  (main) xxx.OuterClass$InnerClass: test message`

It works when the class is extracted out.

Does anyone have an idea why it's not working? Should it work for inner class or I have to extract the class out?

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem and I use this approach

```
private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName() + "." + MyInnerClass.class.getSimpleName());
```

And I configured my log file like this

```
log4j.logger.xxx.yyy.MyClass.MyInnerClass=DEBUG
```